# How I add a role to a channel (best without id)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord 
From discord.ext import commands 

@client.command() 
async def setup(ctx):

await ticket_channel.set_permissions(guild.Ticket-Helper_role, send_messages=True, read_messages=True, add_reactions=True, embed_links=True, attach_files=True, read_message_history=True, external_emojis=True, manage_channels=True)  

client.run("TOKEN")
```

#What's there wrong? I want to add the role to the channel

Answer (score 0):

The Function `channel.set_permissions()` sets the permissions of a user in the channel.So you need to provide a target as the first argument.For example:

```
await ticket_channel.set_permissions(ctx.message.author, send_messages=True, read_messages=True, add_reactions=True, embed_links=True, attach_files=True, read_message_history=True, external_emojis=True, manage_channels=True)
```

I think what you are looking to do is restrict the channel to members with specific roles assigned to them.

for that you might want to read [this documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=text_channel#discord.TextChannel.edit)